# X-Editable re-enable after partial re-render

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, x-editable

I have the following table on a laravel blade that uses x-editable to update some of its fields (note, this is my first ever PHP project so if there are better ways to do this, please share):

```
    <table id="LinksTable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Display</th>
                <th>Link Display Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $link_settings = Link_setting::whereNotNull('link_address')->get();?>
            @foreach($link_settings as $link_setting)
            <tr id="linkRow.{{$link_setting->id}}">
                <td hidden="true">{{$link_setting->id}}</td>
                <td><input id="linkD.{{$link_setting->id}}" name="is_displayed"
                    checked="{{$link_setting->is_displayed}}"
                    onChange="OnDisplayChange(this)" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="listEdit" data-type="text"
                    data-column="display_name" data-url="./link_settings/update"
                    data-pk="{{$link_setting->id}}" data-title="change"
                    data-name="display_name">{{$link_setting->display_name}}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This renders fine the first time and I can edit the display name on any of the rows with it updating the database correctly.
My problem is that I have an "add" button that creates a new object in the database. After added, I need to reload the table to display this entry as well.

```
function RefreshTable() {
    $('.listEdit').editable("destroy");
    $( "#linksTableMainDiv" ).load(location.href + " #LinksTable");
    $('.listEdit').editable();
}
```

The table re-renders fine, but the x-editable breaks, without errors that I can locate.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this post, I ended up reworking this to add a row via javascript, rather than reloading the table. Adding $('.listEdit').editable(); after the table.appendChild(row) enables all the editable fields in the new row. Assigned data-pk=0 to each, and as part of the update controller, returned the id. I then update the row's data-pk elements upon success of the editable function.